# Writing JOIN statement after a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing stored procedure to update base on a column or on another table.
This is what I have :

```
Set Foutcome Case when Tp is > 0 and Rr = 0 
      Then 'settled'
      Else 
      update a set a.Fouctome = b.outcome
      From table_a innerjoin table_b
      On a.datasource= b.datasource
where datasource like '%Bong%'
```

but it doesn't work. please help.

Comment: Seems your sql statement is invalid. First set you are assigning one value as 'settled' then inside else you are framing another update statement which is invalid.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Try the sql below.

```
update a 
set Foutcome=
case when Tp is > 0 and Rr = 0 then 'settled'
else (select top 1 b.outcome from b 
      inner join a on a.datasource= b.datasource  
      where b.datasource like '%Bong%')
end
```

Comment: It will select only one value from the else part.But in OP he is trying to update all records where data source like 'Bongo'

Comment: @Oasis ok, maybe i misunderstand him, if so, i will update the answer later.